# Easiest way to load user-specified double[][] array into java program?

Tags: java, arrays, matlab, input, jar

I am creating a program in java that ned to take in a double[][] array that will be specified by the user. The java program will be executed from MATLAB, where it is fairly easy to create a large array fast. Hence, the example of my program would be something like this:

First create some array in MATLAB:

> T = 1:5:200; 
>   Y = sin(T); 
>   X = [T,Y];

Next is to start the java program from matlab:

> system('java -jar jarname.jar')

Then my challenge comes. **I need to load the matrix X into the Java program** upon execution, since I need this data to make the computation. What do you recon is the best/easiest/least computative method to load this array into my program?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255627/how-to-access-variables-saved-in-mat-file-in-a-built-jar-file-by-matlab-builder/11269971#11269971

Comment: Do you have the option of just running your Java program inside Matlab's JVM? That way it becomes [very straightforward to pass data between the two](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_external/product-overview.html).

Comment: @Notlikethat, that a pretty good point, but I need to restructure my program a bit. I guess what I could do was to create a class with all my arrays (eg Class: DataClass). then in my matlab code I would simply start calling this class to store data. DataClass d1 = new DataClass([MY ARRAY GOES HERE]); 
Then I would execute the .jar file afterward. But do you know if the data from DataClass would be available if executing the .jar file afterwards?

Comment: @Notlikethat restatement: I would probably never call my .jar file but simply execute the program without.

Comment: @SteewDK I guess you'd probably need DataClass to serialise itself to disk so that your .jar can reload it, or use some other method of Java IPC - the details of that are beyond my experience though, sorry.

Comment: Do any of you know how to acess a JAVA package from the MATLAB JVM interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** Thanks to Notlikethat's comment about running it inside Matlab's JVM it does not make sense to use the `.jar` run functionality but instead simply run the Java program as if MATLAB where the main file. This can be done in following way (MATLAB script), assuming that the matlab file and `.jar` file are in the same folder:

```
javaaddpath('..\myFile.jar')
```

from here you can add the packages from your JAVA code by using the import statement:

```
import myPackage.*;
```

From here you are good to go and simply call the methods from the JAVA program using the same syntax as if it where inside `main()` in JAVA.